# Store date using STR_TO_DATE into mysql datetime data type

Tags: php, mysql

This is my INSERT SQL:

```
$insert_pg = "INSERT INTO tblPhotoAlbum (photo_album_title, photo_album_date, photo_album_time, photo_album_detail) VALUES ('".$pg_title."',  'STR_TO_DATE('".$pg_date_post."', '%d-%m-%Y')', '".$current_time."' , '".$pg_detail."')";
```

There are error on the "STR_TO_DATE" part, which php echo this mysql error message:

```
Warining: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '01/05/2014', '%d-%m-%Y')', '17:24:24' , '
ABC Opening 2014

')' at line 1
```

Comment: When you use mysql native functions like now(),curdate(),str_to_date() etc in the insert query you do not need them to be enclosed with single quote since it will be treated as string instead of function.

Answer (score 0):

try to make your query vars in single quote

and remove quote from `'STR_TO_DATE('".$pg_date_post."', '%d-%m-%Y')'`

```
$insert_pg = "INSERT INTO tblPhotoAlbum (photo_album_title, photo_album_date, photo_album_time, photo_album_detail) VALUES ('$pg_title',STR_TO_DATE('$pg_date_post','%Y-%m-%d'), '$current_time' , '$pg_detail')";
```

or

```
$insert_pg = "INSERT INTO tblPhotoAlbum (photo_album_title, photo_album_date, photo_album_time, photo_album_detail) VALUES ('".$pg_title."',  STR_TO_DATE('".$pg_date_post."', '%Y-%m-%d'), '".$current_time."' , '".$pg_detail."')";
```

Comment: Yes, I tried already. But it show me the error "Column 'photo_album_date' cannot be null". I had use datetime picker to get the date variable and pass data using AJAX to PHP.

Comment: then you need to check your all variables values is set or not empty

Comment: The value is set if remove STR_TO_DATE() function and set data type as TEXT in database. If data type set as datetime, value  0000/00/00 00:00:00 in database.

Comment: you need %Y-%m-%d format in strtodate i have changed query

Comment: change STR_TO_DATE('".$pg_date_post."', '%Y-%m-%d') to date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($pg_date_post))

Answer (score 0):

You have the date format around the wrong way. When entering dates into mysql, you should use YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
'-%Y-%m-%d'
```

The insert looks like this:

```
$insert_pg = "INSERT INTO tblPhotoAlbum 
    (photo_album_title, photo_album_date, photo_album_time, photo_album_detail) 
    VALUES ('".$pg_title."',  '".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pg_date_post))."', '".$current_time."' , '".$pg_detail."')";
```

Comment: is '".STR_TO_DATE($pg_date_post, '%d-%m-%Y')."' ok?

Comment: @RakeshSharma Absolutely totally right - and now corrected.

Answer (score 0):

remove the single quotes around `STR_TO_DATE()` function

```
$insert_pg = "INSERT INTO tblPhotoAlbum (photo_album_title, photo_album_date, photo_album_time, photo_album_detail) VALUES ('".$pg_title."',  STR_TO_DATE('".$pg_date_post."', '%d-%m-%Y'), '".$current_time."' , '".$pg_detail."')";
```

Comment: Yes, I remove it already, it show me error that the particular column cant be null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modification and I found my solution.

```
$insert_pg = "INSERT INTO tblPhotoAlbum (photo_album_title, photo_album_date, photo_album_time, photo_album_detail) VALUES ('".$pg_title."',  STR_TO_DATE('".$pg_date_post."','%m/%d/%Y') , '".$current_time."' , '".$pg_detail."')";
```